# What is a recommended high resolution webcam?

Tags: webcam

I would like a new webcam for Ubuntu that can handle a high resolution 1024 x 768 minimum that I can use within applications such as Cheese and Stopmotion for recording videos and taking still images.  With the images preferably at a higher resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You may check for V4L2 (Video for Linux 2) supported webcams at this web page: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices

Cheers